# What is the difference between client-side connection and server-side connection

Tags: java, web-services, security, ssl, client-server

I am fairly new to the web development, I have been going over the release notes of the Java on different platforms like linux (oracle hotspot), AIX and hp-ux. I am actually investigating around the TLS support of each version of java on those platforms. I am coming across information([Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSE_Protocols), [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html)) showing the support for client-side connections and server-side connections. What I do not understand is what is the difference between them.
Does it simply mean that the client trying to connect to a server and the other is server trying to connect to a client? If that is the case why is the TLS support different for both of those connections. I would like to understand the general difference between both of them and what it has to do with the TLS support.

Comment: I guess it would refer to what the client does to connect (client-side) and what the server does to connect (server-side). Remember that the server is ussually the one that needs to present the certificate to authenticate itself to the client (a browser for instance) who will check if the server is who it says it is.

Comment: If that is the case why is the support for TLS different in both the cases? Like this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html I would assume simply that the client and the server are just two machines. Why a particular version of java's support for TLS for a server is different when compared to client?

Comment: I see the same content for client and server in the second table on the link you give. Also, a client should strive to use the highest possible version (nowadays it makes no sense security wise to use anything less than TLS 1.2) but the server, for business reasons, may need to still accept clients using lower security settings. See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html

Comment: @Juan A client always need not be a browser, in our case its a java service calling a server (another service) via HTTP. So what should I be taking away from the Java's support of TLS? Both client and server are java services and why is the support different for both?

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek the second link I provided is the AIX support for java 6 which happens to be same same for client and server luckily but see here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html thats the java 7 support which is different.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek are you trying to say that the java implementation on the client side machines will be different compared to server side? What if both client and server are simply two java services just one calling the other? How will java determine which is client and which is server?

Comment: This is the link I was talking about. For me it shows from top to bottom No/Yes/Yes/Yes for both client and server.

Comment: The one opening the connection is the client, the one sitting idly listening on the socket until a client comes is a server. A given service can be both at the same time. You could also be in a P2P arrangement.

Comment: 1) The browser was just a trivial example. 2) Client and server in this context are programs. To be specific and drilling down into java SSLSocket vs SSLServerSocket. 3) SSL has different versions and within the version different cipher suits. Perhaps something is enabled by default for the server and not for the cliente. If it is not enabled by default, perhaps it can be enabled. SSL is a big subject. Perhaps you would be better off taking it to the security stack echange forum.